# How do I know if my data is meaningful?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption

I am a 17 year old conducting a very scientific experiment into the best method for pulling Christmas crackers in order to get the highest chance of winning the prize. I have 1000 crackers and a team of volunteers, however I am unsure how to process the results, while I am very keen to pursue a career in maths - I have been taught very little so far :( and would really appreciate some simple advice on how to show if my data is meaningful or just a random occurrence.

Currently my data will be collected to give me a %-chance of winning for each method (Number of wins/Total tries). However if I find that twisting a cracker as you pull gave 60% of the test subjects a win. Would this be a statistical outcome or just a fluke? (Assuming the control to be 50%) and if 60% isnt, where is the cutoff? Is there one? I apologize for my naivety in the world of statistics!

I have not run the experiment yet so any suggestions (for example collect every event individually if this helps the analysis) would be much appreciated also.

If there is a simple answer to this question then a few links for me to discover my answers would be very useful indeed.

Thank you and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Welcome  to our site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think running simulations can give good intuition on how common an outcome may be given random chance.

Say you have 10 volunteers who try 100 crackers each. The first five volunteers use strategy #1, while the second five use strategy #2. Both strategies have 50% chance of being successful on any given attempt. Then we can make this simple simulation using R:

```
# Set the parameters for the simulation
Nsim=10000; Ncrackers=100; Nvolunteers=10; Pwin1=.5; Pwin2=.5;
StrategyUsed=c(rep(1,Nvolunteers/2),rep(2,Nvolunteers/2))

dat=matrix(nrow=Ncrackers, ncol=Nvolunteers) # Create matrix to hold the Individual Results
Percent.Success=matrix(nrow=Nsim, ncol=Nvolunteers) # Create matrix to hold the Success Rates

for(sim in 1:Nsim){
  # Simulate the results for each volunteer 
  for(v in 1:Nvolunteers){
    if(StrategyUsed[v]==1){
      dat[,v]<-sample(x=c("win","lose"), size=Ncrackers, 
                      prob=c(Pwin1,1-Pwin1), replace=TRUE)
    }
    if(StrategyUsed[v]==2){
      dat[,v]<-sample(x=c("win","lose"), size=Ncrackers, 
                      prob=c(Pwin2,1-Pwin2), replace=TRUE)
    }
    Percent.Success[sim,v]=100*length(which(dat[,v]=="win"))/Ncrackers
  }
}

#Calculate the difference in average percent success between the two strategies
SuccessDifferences<-rowMeans(Percent.Success[,1:5])-rowMeans(Percent.Success[,6:10])


#Plot a Representative Result
boxplot(c(Percent.Success[1,])~StrategyUsed, range=0, col=c("Red","Blue"), 
        names=c("Strategy #1", "Strategy #2"), ylab="Percent Success")
stripchart(c(Percent.Success[1,])~StrategyUsed, method="jitter", 
           jitter=.2, vertical=T, pch=21,  bg="Grey", cex=1.5, add=T)

#Plot Distribution of all Results
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
hist(Percent.Success[,1:5], col="Red", xlim=c(0,100), 
     xlab="Percent Success", main="Strategy #1")
hist(Percent.Success[,6:10], col="Blue", xlim=c(0,100), 
     xlab="Percent Success", main="Strategy #2")
hist(SuccessDifferences, col="Grey", 
     xlab="Average Difference", main="Strategy #1 - Strategy #2")


#Calculate the percent of simulation results beyond threshold = 10%
100*length(which(abs(SuccessDifferences)>10))/Nsim
```

Here is an example of one of the results:
[image]

Here the top two charts are distribution of percent success from all the simulations. The bottom is the distribution of the differences between the two strategies on average:
[image]

The last line calculates the percent of time the differences between the two groups was greater than 10%. For these specific simulations it was only 0.16%.

```
    #Calculate the percent of simulation results beyond threshold = 10%
    > 100*length(which(abs(SuccessDifferences)>10))/Nsim
[1] 0.16
```

Is an outcome that occurs 0.16% of the time rare enough to be considered not random chance? That is up to you. Also if there were a differences between volunteers using the two strategies it is not correct to then assume the differences is due to the strategy. Other possibilities need to be ruled out, for example maybe volunteers 1:5 got a different batch of crackers than volunteers 6:10, etc.

**Edit:**
Also:

> I have not run the experiment yet so any suggestions (for example
>   collect every event individually if this helps the analysis) would be
>   much appreciated also.

Yes, collect as much data as is practical to collect then plot it vs time and anything else you can think of. The reason is that if you find patterns in the individual events (eg many wins early, fewer later) then there may be other processes going on that may be interesting. For example, perhaps learning is occurring, or fatigue/boredom. These other aspects may differ between the groups and result in differences confounding the theorized effect due to strategy.

The important thing is to be ready to rule out as many explanations for an observed effect as possible, then the ones not ruled out may explain them. Exploring the data that way would not mean you can conclude any apparent patterns are not "random chance", but it may cast doubt on interpreting the results in favor of the strategy effect. Just ruling out that two groups are exactly the same is not very informative without that.

Answer (score 0):

How many methods are you comparing? If you are just comparing 2 methods which are both trialed for each cracker then it is simple. If you have 3 or more methods that could add some complications.

Assuming you have just 2 methods then you can easily test if method A is better than B by assuming that they are both equally good (so the chance of success is 50%) and show that your results would be very unlikely if the chance of success was 50%.

The critical value for this test is

$0.5+0.5\times \frac{1.645}{\sqrt{N}}$

0.5 is the expected rate of winning if A and B are equally good, $0.5\times \frac{2.32}{\sqrt{N}}$ is the amount you'd expect the results to vary if you take N samples.

So taking the example you gave, if you pull 1000 crackers the critical value is $0.5+0.5\times \frac{2.32}{\sqrt{1000}}=0.54$  which means that it is unlikely to have a success rate above 54%. The 2.32 figure in the formula corresponds to being 99% sure that the success rate would be under 54% so if you do get a success rate of 60% then you're over 99% sure that one method is better than the other. With 1000 crackers you'll probably get results showing you are 99% sure of, but in case you want to split up the crackers between several tests you can replace 2.32 with 1.64 in the calculations and you will be 95% sure of the results instead of 99% sure.

Comment: _if you do get a success rate of 60% then you're over 99% sure that one method is better than the other._ This is incorrect. What if there were other differences (eg in some property of the crackers)?

Answer (score 0):

So, a few thoughts... being 17 you probably haven't been exposed to a lot of the mathematics around conditional probabilities and experimental/research design.

I don't know a lot about Christmas crackers, but let's re-frame the question into a question about pulling colored balls out of a bin at random. Say we have 100 colored balls and 900 white balls. The act of pulling a colored ball out is a "win" and not pulling a colored ball is a "loss." From a naive starting point, we would suggest that there is a roughly 10% chance of pulling a colored ball out by chance and chance alone. Perhaps there is a 10% chance of pulling out a "colored christmas cracker?"

A critical decision that we need to make is whether we replace the ball after each draw or whether we set it aside. We would call the former case "with replacement" and the latter case "without replacement."

I'm going to go with the "with replacement" because it is conceptually easier to understand and emits easier mathematics. I'll touch a little bit on without replacement at the end, but won't cover it in detail.

When we operate under the assumption that we are replacing the ball (Christmas cracker) each time, we would assume that there is a 10% chance on each draw of getting the colored ball (cracker). Effectively we would perform a series of draws and count the number of colored balls pulled relative to the number of draws. Say we decide to do 100 total draws, and pull 11 colored balls.

The number of colored balls in the 100 draw sample follows a binomial distribution (not a normal distribution as your tag suggests). There are some similarities and mathematical convergence considerations that may make estimation using a normal distribution a possibility, but we can generally calculate exact probabilities where needed with the binomial distribution.

Here are the probabilities related to a sample size of 100 and a 10% colored ball proportion:

```
Binomial Distribution

   π = 0.1000     n = 100     nπ = 10.000

            Prob     Equal &     Equal &
   r        at r       Above       Below
   -        ----       -----       -----
   0      0.0000      1.0000      0.0000 |
   1      0.0003      1.0000      0.0003 |
   2      0.0016      0.9997      0.0019 |
   3      0.0059      0.9981      0.0078 |--
   4      0.0159      0.9922      0.0237 |----
   5      0.0339      0.9763      0.0576 |---------
   6      0.0596      0.9424      0.1172 |----------------
   7      0.0889      0.8828      0.2061 |------------------------
   8      0.1148      0.7939      0.3209 |------------------------------
   9      0.1304      0.6791      0.4513 |-----------------------------------
  10      0.1319      0.5487      0.5832 |-----------------------------------
  11      0.1199      0.4168      0.7030 |--------------------------------
  12      0.0988      0.2970      0.8018 |--------------------------
  13      0.0743      0.1982      0.8761 |--------------------
  14      0.0513      0.1239      0.9274 |--------------
  15      0.0327      0.0726      0.9601 |---------
  16      0.0193      0.0399      0.9794 |-----
  17      0.0106      0.0206      0.9900 |---
  18      0.0054      0.0100      0.9954 |-
  19      0.0026      0.0046      0.9980 |-
  20      0.0012      0.0020      0.9992 |
  21      0.0005      0.0008      0.9997 |
  22      0.0002      0.0003      0.9999 |
  23      0.0001      0.0001      1.0000 |
  24      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  25      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  26      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  27      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  28      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  29      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  30      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  31      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
  32      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
   \          \           \           \
 100      0.0000      0.0000      1.0000 |
```

In terms of your research, you would conduct a series of trials (each modifying a characteristic of what you are doing, say twisting the cracker) to determine if certain actions yield 100 ball samples with higher or lower proportions than 10%. Of course, a slightly higher or lower rate could be attributed to chance and chance alone, but you could conduct a two sample binomial test to determine if an action taken (i.e. twisting the cracker) yields a statistically significant deviation from what you would expect would be caused by chance and chance alone (in this case 10%).

As we move away from the "with replacement" option and are drawing samples "without replacement", we end up in a place where we no longer have "independence" between sequential draws of a ball (cracker). i.e. the first draw in a sample of 100 draws changes the probability of the second draw being a colored ball/cracker. This case has been well researched and corresponds to what is called the hypergeometric distribution. If you have Excel you can perform the calculation with the "HYPGEOM.DIST" function.

If instead we are taking sequential draws without replacement and we want to know the probability of receiving k colored balls out of the first n draws, we would use the negative binomial distribution.

I would suspect that the easiest way to construct your study is using the "with replacement" option and considering the two-sample binomial test for determining if you have statistical significance for differences between the observed proportions.